# LINQ: How to join two datatable with dynamic keys

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two tables , say dt1 and dt2.
**I want to find the data in dt1 but not matching in dt2 based on some columns.(dynamically)**

The method I figure out is left join two tables and find those whose columns with null value.
But the problem is how can I join them with dynamic column numbers.
For example, if originally I want to join them by N columns, but if 1 of the column in dt2 is empty or null,  then I want to join them by the rest of N-1 columns.

For example:

dt1:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
1A    1B    1C    1D
2A    2B    2C    2D
3A    3B    3C    3D
4A    4B    4C    4D
```

dt2:

```
ColAA  ColBB  ColCC, ColE
1A     1B     null   1E
2A     2X     null   2E
3A     3B     3C     3E
null   null   4C     4E
```

`dt1 left join dt2 by ColA=ColAA, ColB=ColBB and ColC=ColCC`

If one of them is null, then join the rest of the columns.

expected result:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
1A    1B    1C    1D    1E
2A    2B    2C    2D    null
3A    3B    3C    3D    3E
4A    4B    4C    4D    4E
```

The data with null value in ColE is what I want.(2A,2B,2C,2D,null)
Now I can only join them by fixed columns,how can I achieve the scenario above.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the data in row 1 and row 2 are the same. but why in the expected result, row 1 and row 2 are different? as ColE in Row 2 is null?

Comment: if the data isn't there then you cant join on it,  you need some form of consistency otherwise you are going to create a bigger problem in the long run

Comment: What if all the rows have column ColCC null ? All the rows have the same columns that are null or filled with value. But I dont know which column will be null until run time. For example, in round one, ColCC may be null for all rows, and in round two, ColAA and ColBB may be null for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx.

---

It sounds like you want:

```
         from d1 in dt1
         from d2 in dt2
         where (d1.ColA==d2.ColAA or d2.ColAA == null) and
               (d1.ColB==d2.ColBB or d2.ColBB == null) and
               (d1.ColC==d2.ColCC or d2.ColCC == null)
         select new { ..... };
```

---

I'm not sure from your question if this is exactly the query you want, you may want to add for example `and (d1.ColA==d2.ColAA or d1.ColB==d2.ColBB or d1.ColC==d2.ColCC)` so they can't link up on ALL nulls

Comment: In my understanding what OP needs is
`(d1.ColA==d2.ColAA and d2.ColAA != null)`
Join on two columns, provided column value doesn't contain `null` ad shown in the example